# If I just moved, am I more likely to be rejected for a credit card application?

Tags: credit-card, credit

I just moved a couple months ago and wanted to apply for a new credit card, so I could use the points (hotel) on an upcoming trip.

One of the questions was how long you've been at your current address.
If this is a short time, will this hurt my application?
I actually haven't officially changed my address yet (my friends still live at my old place) so I could use this address - is this preferable?

Note that the rent at the new place is double what it was at the old place, if this is relevant.

Comment: You are doing them a favor using credit. They are not doing you a favor extending credit.

Answer (score 8):

In the US, your address is part of the information used to verify your identity. So if you didn't live at the current address long enough (1-2 years), you'll be asked to also provide a previous address. That is to match your information with what is available to the credit card issuer through the credit reporting agencies and verify that you are who you say you are. I do not think moving significantly affects your prospects of getting credit. Paying more rent (without an accompanying increase of income) may though.

Answer (score 1):

citi uses your address to confirm your identity, so using a new address could delay or prevent approval. if you can use your old address, i would suggest you do so, then once you get your card and activate it, immediately update your address with citi.

i believe citi uses your name/address combination to estimate the risk of fraud using a visa product in addition to a credit bureau. if your new address is not yet in their records, they will flag the application as potentially fraudulent even if your credit report is spotless.

longer term, you might consider using an online mailbox or mail forwarding service. in addition to giving you a stable long-term address, it reduces the risks and delays associated with the extremely poor mail forwarding services from the USPS. it also reduces the risk that you will miss something important (e.g. a collection agency letter or government document).